# Where should I look for computing the intersection homology of projective varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, intersection-cohomology, stratifications

I'm learning about intersection cohomology topologically through MacPherson's "[New York Times Article](http://faculty.tcu.edu/gfriedman/notes/ih.pdf)". This is a very nice guide which gives a nice idea on how to use these methods for low-dimensional topological spaces, I'm not sure how I can compute the intersection homology for higher dimensional varieties. For example, if I take the quintic threefold
$$
\textbf{Proj}\left( \frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w,u]}{(x^5 + y^5 + z^2wu^2 + x^3y^2)} \right)
$$
It has jacobian
$$
\text{Jac}(f) = [5x^4 + 3x^2y^2, 5y^4 + 2x^3y, 2zwu^2, z^2u^2, 2z^2wu]
$$
hence ther are the singular loci along the rational curves
$$
x,y,z = 0, \text{ } x,y,u=0
$$
We can form a normal stratification on this variety with these stratum, but now I'm not sure how to actually compute the intersection cohomology groups from here.

Comment: FYI, Greg Friedman's draft book *Singular Intersection Homology* is at http://faculty.tcu.edu/gfriedman/IHbook.pdf

Comment: I don't really know this area - but since you haven't gotten an answer yet - my impression is that people usually do these calculations on algebraic varieties by calculating with D-modules and using the Riemann-Hilbert correspondence.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Thanks for the tip. I'll try and figure out how to find d-modules giving simple objects under the RH-correspondence then.

Comment: I think Alex has it wrong: to use Riemann-Hilbert to compute IH, you would want a good handle on the Riemann-Hilbert correspondent of the IC sheaf.  But not much is known about those "IC D-modules" in general.  We have their generators but almost never their relations.

Comment: The singularities on your 3-fold might look like (C^2/subgroup of SU(2)) x C locally.  In that case it is "rationally smooth", and intersection homology = regular homology with Q-coefficients.