# What techniques are available for constructing D-modules over smooth projective varieties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, d-modules, projective-varieties

I'm trying to learn about D-modules for computing intersection cohomology but I'm having trouble coming up with explicit constructions of D-modules on projective varieties. Since this is an involved process, I'll split this up into multiple questions:

```
1. How do I construct D-modules over complex projective space
2. How do I construct D-modules over smooth projective varieties
3. How can I use the constructions from (1) to find D-modules with
   geometric support on singular varieties?
```

My goal is to start looking at D-modules on Fermat curves
$$
\text{Proj}\left( \frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]}{x^n + y^n - z^n} \right)
$$
and answer the question I raised [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244810/where-should-i-look-for-computing-the-intersection-homology-of-projective-variet)

Comment: For smooth toric varieties (e.g. complex affine and projective space), you might want to take a look at http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869301987319

Comment: If $M$ is a $D$-module (e.g. $M = R$ a ring) then the local cohomology modules $H_I^j(M)$ are $D_R$-modules. This should give you some examples I guess.

Comment: You might find Vilonen's thesis useful, available here: http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002101815

Comment: @AxelStäbler Do you know of any nice introductions to local cohomology accessible to undergraduates?

Comment: Eisenbud's Geometry of Syzygies has a short appendix on local cohomology that may give you a good feel for what's going on. If you know some basic dimension theory then ``24 hours of local cohomology'' is a decent source if you are willing to take certain things for granted or delve into the literature to solve some of the harder exercises. In fact, I ran a seminar based on this not too long ago with students that had taken a second course in algebra.

The material covered in Bruns&Herzog's Cohen-Macaulay rings is also very well presented (but they do not cover as much as other sources).

Comment: The standard references are probably Brodmann&Sharp or Hartshorne's local cohomology lecture notes. Both are probably not suited for undergraduates.